# Stopping looped notifications with VetoableChangeListener

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have a problem with the design of a `VetoableChangeListener`. I implement the `VetoableChangeListener` interface to listen changes of a property in a model class, so when the model fires

```
vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException
```

…I try to save the change in a DB, which could fail (by an `SQLException`, for example). If it fails I throw a `PropertyVetoException` to revert changes in the model.

The model is delegating in a `VetoableChangeSupport` (JDK class), which when it receives a `PropertyVetoException` catches it and notifies the revert to ALL the `VetoableChangeListener`, with the `oldValue`/`newValue` interchanged (later it rethrows the exception), so that the event comes to my class again and I try to save in DB again, etc...

I have a workaround which is that the model does NOT change until nobody throws a `PropertyVetoException`, so that in the `VetoableChangeListener` I FIRST check if the data I'm going to save in the database is NOT equal to the data in the model, if it's equal I simply ignore the change.

Is there another, better workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Your "workaround" is not really a workaround but in fact sounds like the proper solution to me: confirming that there is in fact a change for the current state of the object prior to attempting to "change" the persisted version. This will also be much more efficient (database access is expensive).

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Vetoable change before you change the model, not after...

ie:  if there is a problem, the model is not changed, not revert the model if the change was wrong

Answer (score 0):

To:timyates

Thats exactly what i do, i recive the event, try to update the DB, and it fails, i throw the exception vetoing the change, so that the model is not updated, but the problem is that the VetoableChangeSupport notifies me my own veto, entering in a bucle if i not do the workaround that i explain in the question